# where can i find the addresses of the pancakeswap coin pairs smart contracts

Tags: contract-invocation, pancakeswap, binance

where can I find the smart contract address of all (or the major) coin pairs of the pancakeswap AMM. I can't find it anywhere and searching on google yields random articles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The factory contract - `PancakeFactory` - is here:

https://bscscan.com/address/0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73

If you read the contract, you'll see that `allPairsLength` gives you 14,690 pairs. This refers to the number of `PancakePair`-type contracts.

The addresses can be found by reading the `allPairs` array in `PancakeFactory` by specifying the index you want. In the absence of anything clever, like Uniswap's Subgraph API (see "[All Pairs In Uniswap](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/API/queries/#all-pairs-in-uniswap)") you'll probably just have to write a simple looping function to iterate through the array.

**Edit:**

Actually, this API will give you the top 1,000 pairs... (sorted by reserves)

https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/pairs

Filter on `pair_address`.

Comment: You should really get that address from pancakeswap themselves, since many other people can (and probably have) uploaded that factory contract.  It's in the docs at https://docs.pancakeswap.finance/code/smart-contracts/pancakeswap-exchange/factory-v2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://bscscan.com/ for Binance Contracts. You can use https://etherscan.io/ for Ethereum Contracts.

Here pancakeswap:
https://bscscan.com/token/0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82

Comment: Does not provide a simple way to discover price pairs, though.

Comment: I'll downvote because this is vague and explains nothing. You told 3 obvious things.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what the others answered, if you just want to check if a particular pair exists, you can calculate the address for it in the [following way](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contract-integration/getting-pair-addresses/):

```
address factory = 0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f;
address token0 = 0xCAFE000000000000000000000000000000000000; // change me!
address token1 = 0xF00D000000000000000000000000000000000000; // change me!

address pair = address(uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
  hex'ff',
  factory,
  keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1)),
  hex'96e8ac4277198ff8b6f785478aa9a39f403cb768dd02cbee326c3e7da348845f'
))));
```

Note that:

- `token0` must be strictly less than `token1` by sort order.

Answer (score 1):

calculate pair address with token0 and token1 on pancakeswap:

```
address factory = 0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73;
address token0 = 0xCAFE000000000000000000000000000000000000; // change me!
address token1 = 0xF00D000000000000000000000000000000000000; // change me!

address pair = address(uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
  hex'ff',
  factory,
  keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1)),
  hex'0x00fb7f630766e6a796048ea87d01acd3068e8ff67d078148a3fa3f4a84f69bd5' // ref: https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-sdk/blob/7d81106174e16d1f1c6c91a93558736282a39ec1/src/constants.ts#L24
))));
```